# OK button for JavaScript confirm not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am facing an issue, where clicking OK button on JavaScript confirm popup is not working in IE11. When user clicks the button, nothing happens. This happens only for one user and is working successfully for most users on IE11. Ideally on clicking OK, the popup should close and the event handler for the button `btnSave` should get called. However, this is not happening and clicking the OK button does not close the confirmation popup.

I wanted to know whether this could be due to some setting in IE, which this particular user has made that is causing the issue.

Following is the piece of code:

```
btnSave.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return confirm('Do you want to save?')");
```

Comment: As you are saying its only one user, can you ask the user to hard refresh and clear their cache? Does this make a difference? get the user to press ctrl+shift+del on their IE browser and delete browsing history. If you are using localstorage instruct them to clear their browser local storage and hard refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a similar problem a few years ago. The following code worked for me in all cases:

```
btnSave.OnClientClick = "if (!confirm('Do you want to save?')) return false;";
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I am looking for a code change since this issue has been reported by only one user.